# changing Hand symbol to Mouse pointer while clicking of node of D3 tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 clickable tree layout.If we place the mouse on any node,moouse pointer is changing to Hand symbol.how to avoid it.I want mouse pointer even while clicking of a node

Comment: [This article](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/stylesc.htm) should help.

Comment: Hi Lars..it talks about how to change the mouse pointer.but my problem is when i palce the cursor on any node of tree layout it is changing to pointer...i need to avoid it.by default d3 is supporting it as tree  layout is clickable

Comment: On your css styling, just set cursor to default, like this: `.node{cursor:default;}`, assuming your nodes have a class attribute of `node`. You can also set this in code in your node selection: `.style("cursor","default")`.

Comment: yes ,Exactly it worked